# How to convert date to fiscal year and fiscal quarter when my fiscal year does not start in Jan?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a date field like 2022-04-19 and want to be able to convert it to fiscal year field 2022-Q3 since the fiscal year starts in August. How do I write the big query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can shift the date forward by 5 months to get a quarter cycle which starts with Jan. Note that to handle dates correctly we are truncating dates to start of month.

Finally we format correctly

```
WITH table AS (
SELECT 
DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC (DATE "2022-04-19", MONTH) ,INTERVAL 5 MONTH ) AS date
)

SELECT  FORMAT_DATE("%G- %Q", ) as format_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```sql
SELECT date,
    concat(fiscal_year,'-Q',fiscal_month) as fiscal_quarter
FROM
(SELECT 
    date,
    extract(year from date_add(date, interval 5 month)) as fiscal_year,
    extract(quarter from date_add(date, interval 5 month)) as fiscal_month
FROM `your-table`)
ORDER BY date;
```

Output:
[image]